# Is it ok to move dog crate from room to room?

Tags: dogs, crate

I am getting a labrador puppy in a few weeks and we are planning on crate training him. We are trying to decide where to place the crate and we think that we want him to be in the living room with us when we are in there, but at night and when we are out we would rather he was in a different room. Is there any negative effects caused by moving the crate to different locations? Should the crate be placed in a single location and left there all the time?

Answer (score 3):

They purpose of crate training is to establish a safe space for your dog, where it can go it it wants some space.

You are aiming to establish it as such, and so I would suggest moving it is redundant. 
Your dog will seek you out when it wants company anyway.

You should avoid disturbing the dog when crated - that is part of how you establish it as "safe"

So I would say, just position it in its overnight location, and leave it at that. Your dog will move around normally anyway.  Maybe a dog bed in your main room would be appropriate too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to crate train him for life, I would suggest getting two separate crates. That way he will know that he has his place in the living room during the day and he has a place at night when he sleeps.

You could move the one crate back and forth but this might become a hassle. Plus, he is going to get big so establishing a routine now will be much helpful later. My vote is, get two crates.

Answer (score 0):

Another room when you sleep?  They are pack animals and sleep together.  Dog misses his/her mom and litter.  The dog wants to sleep in the room with you where he/she can smell you and hear you.  Even put the crate up so they can see you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am sorry I know this is an old post but I came across this on google and it's wrong information, I happen to be a certified dog trainer and the fact that every one is saying that moving the crate around is against the purpose of crate training is not accurate for me.
crate training is creating a positive association with the crate not where it's placed, and your dog needs to be around you or else he'll feel lonely, anyway this is my opinion and I use two crates one in the bedroom where my dog sleeps(when I can hear him)and  another I move around, i found [an article](https://cratetrainingcenter.com/can-you-move-a-dog-crate-from-room-to-room/) on this point you can read for more details but in my opinion it's totally fine to move it.