# How Can I Bring My Newly Mid-Crate-Training Puppy to My Partner's House to Sleep?

Tags: dogs, training, crate

I have a 13-week old puppy for almost a week now. He's a very good dog but with a lot of very normal puppy qualities (about 50% there on potty training, pretty good at crate-training, chewing on everything until I give him a toy instead, etc).

Normally (pre-dog) I spend the weekend at my partner's house who also has a dog (three-year-old). Also very well behaved but doesn't do crate-training -- sleeps on the bed, etc.

Is there a solution I'm missing to still stay at her house without accidentally messing up my puppy's crate-training?

I originally thought I'd bring the crate with me, but I don't think her dog would allow a dog to be in a crate overnight without trying to play, etc. And the apartment isn't big enough to separate them unfortunately. (Same with my place.) I could let him sleep on the bed there but he's doing a good job at crate-training and don't want to accidentally mess it up. Any ideas I haven't thought of? Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10956/is-it-ok-to-move-dog-crate-from-room-to-room

Comment: @Henders       Thanks! Definitely semi-related. I have a few more hurdles I think considering it's an entirely different apartment and there's another dog there. I'm open to letting him sleep on the bed over there theoretically because I don't plan on crate-training him forever, but I just don't want him to lose what he's learned since he's doing a good job so far.

Comment: The answer on the other questions suggests that it is about establishing a safe space. It looks like moving the dog will defeat this idea of a 'safe space'.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider getting a smaller travel carrier, one just big enough for your pup to lay down or stand up in? You could get a soft sided carrier and place it on the bed beside you when it's time to go to bed. If the other dog in the house is not allowed on furniture then it knows better than to jump on furniture and get near the puppy. If the older dog IS allowed on furniture, they could still smell each other, lay next to each other, OR be separated by bed without having to shut doors and close off space to the rest of the house (puppy with you, grown dog on other bed if there is a 2nd bed) OR separated by human, a dog on each side.